# Trying to change font color in fabricjs application, get "Cannot set property 'onchange' of null"

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, spectrumjs

I get "Cannot set property 'onchange' of null" console error. When I try to wrap the handler in a `window.onload` function, it makes the function I am trying to call undefined. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that Spectrumjs "sp-choose" button does not exist until it the color picker is opened.

Here is a [link to my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scottrrr/hc10jzbp/18/) that best shows the issue.

Comment: The id `sp-chooser` is not generated even after click on color picker.

Comment: It's generated when you click on the "choose" button.

Comment: I edited the fiddle to show the color picker. But it's still not identifying the 'sp-choose' element.

Comment: What about attaching the `onchnage` function after click on "choose" button which means after generated `sp-chooser`?

Comment: When I click on `sp-choose` doesn't that fire the call to `fontcolorHandler`? The page is loaded and `sp-choose` does exist. If I run `function fontcolorHandler (id, fn, eventName) {
    console.log(id); // returns sp-choose` But console reads `TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null`

Comment: Not an answer but a workaround. I ended up reworking the code so it is all triggered only when that button is clicked with this function `$("#custom-3 .sp-choose").on('click', function(obj){...` It works and is doing what I need.